# How to increase applicationIconBadgeNumber in background app when localNotification fires?

Tags: iphone, localnotification

How do I increase the value of applicationIconBadgeNumber when a localNotification fires and my app is running in the background?

Comment: I would do exactly the same thing as you.
Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you even look the `UILocalNotification` documentation ? There's a `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property...

Comment: I did not understand the purpose of applicationIconBadgeNumber correctly. So yes, I read the UILocalNotification doc and it is clear now. Thanks!